# How to know which feature a bundle comes from ？

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, pde, p2

Knowing the name of a **bundle**, how to know which **feature** it came from ?

Comment: Not an ideal answer, but since installed features are unpacked onto disk, `grep` the feature.xml files?